# django 1.3 validate form field that are programmatically created

Tags: python, django

I have a form in which I programmatically generate the fields on runtime. In the clean method inside my form, when i print cleaned_data i get nothing. Is it possible to access the data of the field that was generated at runtime?

wizard.py

```
        for i in lobj:
            form.fields['list[%s]' % i.id] = forms.CharField(label=i.title, widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
```

forms.py

```
class SelectList_Form(forms.Form):

    param = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        super(SelectList_Form, self)
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        try:

            print cleaned_data
            if cleaned_data['1-list[]']:
                print cleaned_data['1-list[]']


        except Exception, e:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Must select at least one of the lists below'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the call to parent class clean method line be?
`super(SelectList_Form, self).clean()`

Comment: thanks @madhusdan, you saved my time. I was going into circles and i don't know how come i never noticed this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

mudhusudan brought my attention to the fact that I missed to place clean method in the super call. Below code is the fix

```
class SelectList_Form(forms.Form):

    param = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        super(SelectList_Form, self).clean()
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        try:

            print cleaned_data
            if cleaned_data['1-list[]']:
                print cleaned_data['1-list[]']


        except Exception, e:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Must select at least one of the lists below'))
```